# Using doseq/for with infinite sequences

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

in Clojure, one can iterate over a sequence by the help of the function `for` or similarly with `doseq` for side-effects and getting nil as return value:

```
(doseq [x (range 3)]
    (prn x))

; 0
; 1
; 2
```

for the case the sequence is infinite, there is a way to introduce a break condition:

```
(doseq [x (range) :while (< x 3)]
    (prn x))
```

This would produce the same output as above.

As a specialty there is a very interesting behavior when you use more than one sequence. As the documentation calls it: "Collections are iterated in a nested fashion, rightmost fastest".

```
(doseq [x (range 3) y (range 3)]
    (prn x y))

; 0 0
; 0 1
; 0 2
; 1 0
; 1 1
; 1 2
; 2 0
; 2 1
; 2 2
```

What happens however, if the sequences are infinite again. When the last one is infinite, it works quite well. this would work equally as the example before:

```
(doseq [x (range 3) y (range) :while (< y 3)]
    (prn x y))
```

If the first one is infinite, the resulting output is as expected, but for some reasons the loop does not stop after the last line is printed. In other words: the repl keeps working.

```
(doseq [x (range) y (range 3) :while (< x 3)]
    (prn x y))
```

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: had a look at `(source doseq)`  - and optionally on `(macroexpand '<your-doseq-expr>)` ?

Comment: oh, just had a look. A bit too deep for my knowledge until now...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
(doseq [x (range) 
        y (range 3) 
        :while (< x 3)]
  (prn x y))
```

It should be:

```
(doseq [x (range) 
        :while (< x 3)
        y (range 3)]
  (prn x y))
```

...which terminates.

Think of it this way:

```
(doseq [x (range)]
  (doseq [y (range 3) 
          :while (< x 3)]
    (prn x y)))
```

vs:

```
(doseq [x (range)
        :while (< x 3)]
  (doseq [y (range 3)]
    (prn x y)))
```

In the original version, outer loop is infinite, having that `:while` in the inner loops doesn't make a difference. The loop continues on, it just does nothing. In the fixed version `:while` terminates the outer loop.

Comment: Wow, I never knew the order/placement of the condition was significant.

Answer (score 1):

Given muhuk's excellent explanation, it seems like a good argument for being explicit and not over-compressing the code.  So maybe like this:

```
(doseq [x (range 3)]
  (doseq [y (range 3)]
    (prn x y)))
```

if you can control the input sequence, or like this:

```
(let [x-vals    (range)
      y-vals    (range) ]
  (doseq [x x-vals :while (< x 3)]
    (doseq [y y-vals :while (< y 3)]
      (prn x y))))
```

if the input sequence (eg `x-vals` or `y-vals`) is provided to you from the caller.